# How to get the expanding maximum of a pandas groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to calculate the expanding maximum for each 15 minute interval in a dataframe. Here is some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
indexcol = pd.date_range('01-01-2015 00:00:00','01-02-2015 00:00:00',freq='1min',tz='Europe/Amsterdam')
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':np.random.random(len(indexcol))},index=indexcol)
df = (df - 0.5).cumsum()
```

Which looks like this:

```
                              value
2015-01-01 00:00:00+01:00   0.048814
2015-01-01 00:01:00+01:00   0.264003
2015-01-01 00:02:00+01:00   0.366766
2015-01-01 00:03:00+01:00   0.411649
2015-01-01 00:04:00+01:00   0.335304
                             ...
2015-01-06 23:56:00+01:00 -38.901560
2015-01-06 23:57:00+01:00 -39.387544
2015-01-06 23:58:00+01:00 -39.015269
2015-01-06 23:59:00+01:00 -39.151855
2015-01-07 00:00:00+01:00 -39.166035
```

[image: Visualization of sample data]

Now I want to calculate the expanding maximum for each 15 minutes. So I tried the following code:

```
df['max'] = df['value'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15min')).expanding().max()
```

Unfortunately this gives the following error:

```
IndexError: index 97 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 97
```

I don't understand why this fails. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you don't need to use the expanding() function. After fiddling around a while I fixed it by using the cummax() function of pandas (thanks to [INGl0R1AM0R1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12845199/ingl0r1am0r1)'s answer which pointed me to the word cumulative, instead of expanding.)

```
df['max'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15min')).cummax()
```

This results in the following data:
[image: Cummax of data]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15min')).cummax()
```

You dont need the expanding function, it is redundant.
Your error was caused, because the expanding function grabbed the grouped by object, and tried to apply the max, but without the min window frame it didnt know what to do. So it gave you that error. Also nice question

Comment: Thanks for replying, however, I really want an expanding maximum. Not just the maximum per 15 minutes. If I want that I can easily resample the data and don't need to use the groupby function at all. I want an expanding maximum for each 15 minute interval, and specified per minute. By the way, I don't understand why, but your answer leads to many NaN values.

Comment: Ah now i get you want the cumalative max per minute? For each minute it increments slowly?

Comment: Yeah kind of. I thought it was called the expanding max. But cumulative max could also be correct. I want the cumulative max calculated on a per minute basis, but the cumulative max needs to reset each 15 minutes. So after the first 15 minutes, the cumulative max resets, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for replying, it pointed me in the right direction (cumulative instead of expanding)! I managed to solve it!

Comment: jcnc just a tipperoo friend usually recomended, to show your end result to avoid such confusions hahaha. I thought you were making two window logics

Comment: Yes I wanted to include the desired result in the question, however, I did not yet know how to get it haha. I included the results in my answer though. But next time I'll spend more time on explaining the desired result. Thanks!